# How can I set the default (user defined) listing mode in Midnight Commander?

Tags: mc

I defined my own listing mode and I'd like to make it permanent so that on the next mc start my defined listing mode will be set. 
I found no configuration file for mc.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably `Auto save setup` turned off in `Options->Configuration` menu.

You can save the configuration manually by `Options->Save setup`.

Panels setup is saved to `~/.config/mc/panels.ini`.

Comment: Just tried this in MC 4.8.29. On every restart the listing format is reset. Auto Save Setup is ON. `~/.config/mc/panels.ini` is always 0-sized. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

**2023 SOLUTION**

mc 4.8.29.

The setup saving logic is quite counter-intuitive.

The manual "Options > Save setup" seems to cover both `~/.config/mc/ini` and `~/.config/mc/panels.ini`.

The "Options > Configuration... > Auto save setup", despite looking similar, only covers `ini` by default. To make it cover `panels.ini` as well, you have to turn on the separate option: "Options > Panel options... > Auto save panels setup".

Thus, after setting up your preferred panel listing formats, either use "Options > Save Setup" manually, or turn on BOTH automatic ones.